# Remove certain substrings from name column

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I have 2 kind of Strings in column "NAME":

```
Berlin 
Reg.-Bez. Hannover
```

I need a new colum "NAME2" changing the cities to:

```
Berlin
Hannover
```

I have this so far:

```
if("NAME" LIKE 'Reg.-%',xxxx,"NAME")
```

Can you help me with "xxxx"?

I tried

```
xxxx= "right( "field", length("field" ) - 10)"
```

but that's not working.

Or can i just use something like

```
trim('Reg.-Bez. ')
```

Comment: `substr("field", 10)` should return the part of "field" after the first 10 characters

Answer (score 5):

Will you try this:

```
regexp_replace("NAME", 'Reg[.][-]Bez[.]\\s', '')
```

This will remove `Reg.-Bez.` (including a space at the end)